# how to divide a world map based on local areas with python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pygal

I want to divide a world map based on local areas of every country.
but when I searched about it on the internet, I found a library called pygal that could make a world map.
But I want a library to access all data about all continents and all countries into it and all local areas of a country and some data about its populations, its area and geolocation of it (for example: the center of the local area as latitude and longitude).
i could show my data by pygal with the following code :

show some countries :

```
import pygal
wm = pygal.maps.world.World()
wm.title = "North, Central, and South America"

wm.add("NOrth America", ["ca","mx","us"])
wm.add("Central America", ["bz","cr","gt","hn","ni","pa","sv"])

wm.render_to_file("americas.svg")
```

---

show continets :

```
import pygal

supra = pygal.maps.world.SupranationalWorld()
supra.add('Asia', [('asia', 1)])
supra.add('Europe', [('europe', 1)])
supra.add('Africa', [('africa', 1)])
supra.add('North america', [('north_america', 1)])
supra.add('South america', [('south_america', 1)])
supra.add('Oceania', [('oceania', 1)])
supra.add('Antartica', [('antartica', 1)])

supra.render_to_file("continents.svg")
```

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer. What do you still need that the current code does not give you?

Comment: Actually I want to access all data about all countries and all local regions.
Before using pygal I must populate these data and then I can use this pygal to show this data.
Currently I`m looking for a good library to gather these data.